# How to make image transition smoothly with toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I used transition to make the change smooth and it is working, but for the image I couldn't setup well. How can I fix this?

I tried this:

```js
var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
lightsOff.style.display = "block";
lightsOn.style.display = "none";
```

And this:

```js
var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
lightsOff.style.display = "none";
lightsOn.style.display = "block";
```

Here is the full code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".one, .three, .five");
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
      if (element.classList.contains("one")) {
        var logoElement = element.querySelector('.logo');
        var h2Element = element.querySelector('h2');
        var sloganElement = element.querySelector('.slogan');
        logoElement.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        sloganElement.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        h2Element.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
      } else if (element.classList.contains("three")) {
        var textThreeOne = element.querySelector('.text-threeone');
        var textThreeTwo = element.querySelector('.text-threetwo');
        var p = element.querySelector('.text-threetwo + p');
        textThreeOne.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        textThreeTwo.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        p.style.setProperty('color', 'white');

        var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
        var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
        lightsOff.style.display = "block";
        lightsOn.style.display = "none";

        var blackmoon = document.querySelector(".moon");
        blackmoon.style.display = "block";
      } else if (element.classList.contains("five")) {
        var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
        var textarea = element.querySelector('textarea');
        var submitBtn = element.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
        inputs.forEach(input => {
          input.style.setProperty('background-color', '#1f1f1f');
          input.style.setProperty('color', '#ffffff');
        });
        textarea.style.setProperty('background-color', '#1f1f1f');
        textarea.style.setProperty('color', '#ffffff');
        submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#1f1f1f');
        // Toevoegen muisover kleur
        submitBtn.style.setProperty('transition', 'background-color 0.2s');
        submitBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#101010');
        });
        submitBtn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
          submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#1f1f1f');
        });
        var contact = element.querySelector('#contact');
        var pOne = element.querySelector('.five>p+p');
        var pTwo = element.querySelector('.five>p+p+p');
        contact.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        pOne.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
        pTwo.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
      } else {
        element.style.setProperty('color', 'white');
      }
    } else {
      if (element.classList.contains("one")) {
        var logoElement = element.querySelector('.logo');
        logoElement.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        var sloganElement = element.querySelector('.slogan');
        sloganElement.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        var sloganElement = element.querySelector('h2');
        sloganElement.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');

        var blackmoon = document.querySelector(".moon");
        blackmoon.style.display = "none";
      } else if (element.classList.contains("three")) {
        var textThreeOne = element.querySelector('.text-threeone');
        var textThreeTwo = element.querySelector('.text-threetwo');
        var p = element.querySelector('.text-threetwo + p');
        var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
        var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
        lightsOff.style.display = "none";
        lightsOn.style.display = "block";

        p.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        textThreeOne.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        textThreeTwo.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
      } else if (element.classList.contains("five")) {
        var inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
        var textarea = element.querySelector('textarea');
        var submitBtn = element.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
        inputs.forEach(input => {
          input.style.setProperty('background-color', '#efefef');
          input.style.setProperty('color', 'black');

        });
        textarea.style.setProperty('background-color', '#efefef');
        textarea.style.setProperty('color', 'black');

        submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#437bff');
        submitBtn.style.setProperty('color', 'white');

        // Toevoegen muisover kleur
        submitBtn.style.setProperty('transition', 'background-color 0.2s');
        submitBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#133edb');
        });
        submitBtn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
          submitBtn.style.setProperty('background-color', '#437bff');
        });

        var contact = element.querySelector('#contact');
        var pOne = element.querySelector('.five>p+p');
        var pTwo = element.querySelector('.five>p+p+p');
        contact.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        pOne.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
        pTwo.style.setProperty('color', '#353535');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.one,
.three,
.five {
  transition: 1500ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="darkmodebtn" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
  <img id="lights-off" src="../images/darkmode.png" style="display: none;">
  <img id="lights-on" src="../images/ABC.png">
</div>
```

Comment: you can't "smooth" between none <-> block. It's yes/no. The only way is to use javascript. From on to off: you animate first opacity to 0, and after put display none. From off to on: you put opacity to0, display block, animate opacity to 1. There is variation using visibility hidden, visible using same idea

Comment: Can you send me the right code please? Need I to write like this? :                 var lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
                var lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
                
                lightsOff.style.opacity = 0;
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                  lightsOff.style.display = "none";
                }, 1000);

Comment: you have to add the function toggle_light_display in your script. When you call the function from your code with 'off' as parameters if you want light-off "on" (light-on off), and 'on' parameters if you want light-on "on" (light-off off)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.light-on1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.container1 img');
  toggle_light_on_display(el);
})
document.querySelector('.light-off1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.container1 img');
  toggle_light_off_display(el);
})

function toggle_light_on_display(el) {
  el.style.opacity = '0';
  el.style.display = 'block';
  const to = setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.opacity = '1';
    clearTimeout(to); // lot better to clear timeout when no more use
  }, 200) // this little delay is for the display block to finish
}

function toggle_light_off_display(el) {
  el.style.opacity = '0';
  const to = setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    clearTimeout(to); // lot better to clear timeout when no more use
  }, 500) // this delay is the delay of the transition
}

document.querySelector('.light-on2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.container2 img');
  toggle_light_on_visibility(el);
})
document.querySelector('.light-off2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.container2 img');
  toggle_light_off_visibility(el);
})

function toggle_light_on_visibility(el) {
  el.style.opacity = '0';
  el.style.visibility = 'visible';
  const to = setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.opacity = '1';
    clearTimeout(to); // lot better to clear timeout when no more use
  }, 200) // this little delay is for the visibility visible to finish
}

function toggle_light_off_visibility(el) {
  el.style.opacity = '0';
  const to = setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    clearTimeout(to); // lot better to clear timeout when no more use
  }, 500) // this delay is the delay of the transition
}
```

```css
.container1 img {
  display: none;
  transition: 500ms ease-in all;
}

.container2 img {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 500ms ease-in all;
}
```

```html
<button class="light-on1">light-on display</button>
<button class="light-off1">light-off display</button>
<div class="container1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600" alt="">
</div>

<button class="light-on2">light-on visibility</button>
<button class="light-off2">light-off visibility</button>
<div class="container2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/800/600" alt="">
</div>
```

So here you have the 2 versions, display and visibility.

To see the real usage difference, in the HTML, put the block of container 2 and buttons 2 before the 1. With visibility the space is preserve.

For the code, I left on and off as 2 functions, can grouped in 1 as a toggle function. Detection could be done on style opacity in first case and visibility on second.

You can play with the delay. Note that there is a little delay to put when changing display to on and visibility to visible. Browser need little time to render that.

You can play with transition on image and its delay. If you change transition timing, change the off delay accordingly.

You can adapt this for your code easily.

Comment: how can i implement this in my existing code

Comment: andre you have everything to implement it in you code! You just have to add the function to your code and to call them. I can't use your code, lot of lines can't be reproduce outside your project

Comment: got it. I am still learning javascript. and in your code you have different html code then mine, different classes. in my code I had darkmode toggle with onclick. it seems different and cant know what to put where :( I writed all my code above and all elements are changing with transition except for images :(

Answer (score 0):

ok new snippet, I mixed the 2 functions in 1 using your html

```js
function myFunction() {
  const lightsOff = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
  const lightsOn = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
  if (lightsOff.style.display === 'none') {
    toggle_light_display('off');
  } else {
    toggle_light_display('on');
  }
}

function toggle_light_display(test) {
  let el1, el2;
  if (test === 'off') {
    el1 = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
    el2 = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
  } else {
    el1 = document.querySelector("#lights-off");
    el2 = document.querySelector("#lights-on");
  }
  el1.style.opacity = '0';
  let to = setTimeout(function() {
    el1.style.display = 'none';
    clearTimeout(to);
    el2.style.opacity = '0';
    el2.style.display = 'block';
    to = setTimeout(function() {
      el2.style.opacity = '1';
      clearTimeout(to);
    }, 200)
  }, 500)
}
```

```css
img {
  transition: 500ms ease-in all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="darkmodebtn" onclick="myFunction()">switch</button>
</div>
<div>
  <img id="lights-off" src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600" alt="" style="display: none;">
  <img id="lights-on" src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/800/600" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you I was waiting for your answer. here I added my code the code's of the images are on line 29 and line 93 https://jsfiddle.net/q5fL2bma/ where I have to add your javascript code? and what I have to delete from my code?